# PostgreSQL running select on dblink-view fetches the whole remote table

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I have a database that contains a table `tbl_files` that I want to access from a different database. The tables size is around 140 GiB. For this I have created a view on that remote table, that uses a `dblink` to access it:

```
create or replace view v_remote_tbl_files as
select *
from dblink('postgresql://my_user:my_pw@my_cluster:5432/my_schema', 'select * from tbl_files')
     as t1(file_id bigint, file_name varchar(255), file_data bytea);
```

Now if I run a simple:

`select count(*) from v_remote_tbl_files;`

I would expect PostgreSQL to run the actual operation on the remote database via the dblink and just return the count. However, it will load the 140 GiB into the local instance, which I can actively observe using `df -Th`. This way the query will run for over an hour. The same happens for `where`-clauses. PostgreSQL always first fetches the whole table.

Is there a way to force PostgreSQL to run the query on the remote and just return the result?

Comment: Of course it supports dblink.  Perhaps you meant it doesn't support FDW? But, 9.6 does support that too, and that is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: You are right, I misinterpreted the 'unsupported versions'. I will try with FDW.